# Getting `error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token`

Tags: c, identifier

Getting the `error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token` on the closing curly bracket before `void push()`
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct stack
{
    int no;
    struct stack *next;
};
struct stack *p,*temp,*head;
void main()
{
    void push();
    void pop();
    void display();
    int choice;
    while(1);
        printf("\n 1 Push");
        printf("\n 2 Pop");
        printf("\n 3 Display");
        printf("\n 4 Quit");
        printf("\n Enter your option: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            push();
            break;
        
        case 2:
            pop();
            break;

        case 3:
            display();
            break;

        default:
            exit(0);
        }
    }
} //getting the error here
void push()
{
    temp=(struct stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    printf("\n Enter no: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp->no);
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        temp->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
    printf("\n Element %d is pushed in to the stack", temp->no);
}
void pop()
{
    p=head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        head=head->next;
        printf("Element %d is popped from the stack", p->no);
        free(p);
    }
}
void display()
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n stack is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        p=head;
        printf("\n the elements present in the stack:\n");
        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d", p->no);
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
file2.c:40:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token
 }
 ^
```

Comment: Check your braces.

Comment: Try indenting your code correctly: the problem(s) should become obvious.  Also, what do you think `while(1);` does?

Comment: What does the brace `}` after the `switch` statement close?

Comment: Why are you declaring  functions inside `main`? Take these out.

Comment: C is not Python.  Indentation is a matter of convention, style, and code readability, not of function.  As such, running your code through an automatic formatter can help you spot places where the intent encoded in your indentation does not match your actual syntax.  There are many such formatters available.  I tend to use [Code Beautify](https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier) when I want an online formatter for quick & easy use, though I use a different code style than it produces for my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that (in `main`):

```
while(1);
```

Should be:

```
while (1) {
```